# My screen brightness fn keys don't work.

Tags: keyboard, suspend, sleep

I have a Viao VGN-CS16T.   Whenever my computer wakes from sleep, the keyboard does not function.  Also, I cannot click and the trackpad is erratic. It might be related to the multimedia keys above the keyboard.  whenever I touch them, the trackpad goes crazy.  I already asked about that in another post.

Answer (score 1):

Edit "*/etc/default/grub*" as root.

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Now, look for the line that looks like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Append "*atkbd.reset*" to the end of that line, before the end quotes, so that the line now looks something like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash atkbd.reset"
```

Save and close the file, and run the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now, reboot, and test suspending and resuming your laptop. Your issues should now be resolved.

Comment: That doesnt change the issue